# How to generate some report for test cases result in unit test?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, kif, kif-framework

In my application I am using KIF framework for testing. Now for all test cases in my class I want to generated file with all cases and their result. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open Terminal run the following command

> sudo install ocunit2junit

then move project folder (cd project path)
and run following command

> xcodebuild test -workspace appName.xcworkspace -scheme schemName
>   -destination 'platform=iOS,id=deviceID' 2>&1|ocunit2junit